# How to convert this API get() result into JSON object?

Tags: json, angular, observable

API endpoint returning an observable. When I am trying to retrieve any property of the returned object, it is showing that the property does not exist on type {}

**This is the endpoint result**

```
{
  "base": "EUR",
  "date": "2018-04-08",
  "rates": {
    "CAD": 1.565,
    "CHF": 1.1798,
    "GBP": 0.87295,
    "SEK": 10.2983,
    "EUR": 1.092,
    "USD": 1.2234,
  }
}
```

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ConvertResultModel } from './converter/convert-result-model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServiceProviderService {
  private baseUrl = 'https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  getLatest():Observable<ConvertResultModel>{
    return this.http.get<ConvertResultModel>(this.baseUrl);
  }
}
```

**converter.component.ts**

```
import { ServiceProviderService } from './../service-provider.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-converter',
  templateUrl: './converter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./converter.component.css']
})
export class ConverterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private serviceProvider: ServiceProviderService) { }
  private resultSet = {};
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.serviceProvider.getLatest().subscribe(data => this.resultSet = data);
    console.log(this.resultSet.base);
  }
}
```

**convert-result-model.ts**

```
export interface ConvertResultModel {
  base: number;
  date: string;
  rates: any[];
}
```

**ERROR in src/app/converter/converter.component.ts(17,32): error TS2339: Property 'base' does not exist on type '{}'.**

Comment: replace `private resultSet = {};` with something like `private resultSet:any = {};` or `private resultSet:any = null;` its all about type checking. something good in typescript.

Comment: The error might also be that you're console.logging a value that doesn't exist yet. The service call before your console.log is asynchronous, so it's called and before the data comes back you're trying to do the console.log

Comment: What do you have in your response (data)?

Comment: @robert , the JSON file mentioned on top is returned as the response.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Add "any" keyword to this line: `private resultSet: any = {};` as @MishelParkour wrote.

Comment: `private resultSet: ConvertResultModel` without a default value (can use `*ngIf` in the template to check for truthyness before rendering), then move the console.log() statement into the subscribe at very minimum to wait for result to resolve before logging `this.serviceProvider.getLatest().subscribe(data => { this.resultSet = data; console.log(this.resultSet.base) });`

Comment: @robert I added more detailed answer.

Comment: @SaptarshiDas I posted an answer with more details please let me know if it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

Its all about type checking in typescript. Which is something good but sometimes you don't want to define type of everything.

So you may want to replace

```
private resultSet = {};
```

With something like

```
private resultSet:any = {};
// or 
//private resultSet:any = null;
```

Or define a class or interface and set type of `resultSet` to that class or interface. Something like:

```
public interface ResultSet{
  base: String;
  // etc
}
```

and then

```
private resultSet:ResultSet= {} as ResultSet;
// or 
//private resultSet:ResultSet= null;
```

But my suggestion is try to practice using power of typescript which helps you catch some errors in compile time instead of runtime

Comment: I have already created the interface. I don't whether it is correct or not. And the problem has been resolved when I do not specify any return type. Problem persist if the return type of getLatest() is an Observable.

Comment: If I try to extract "rates" from variable named 'data' which receives the returned result from getLatest() method, it is extractable. If I assign it to any other class variable of component class, then "rates" become nonextractable.

Comment: @SaptarshiDas so you are saying your codes work fine if you set type of resultSet to `any`? If yes then thats the solution to your problem. And that's the way to go. About interface approach I cant guess what you have done wrong and I should see more codes. probably the interface and any errors you get